# How to label a word inside a paragraph?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

The idea is to place `\LBL{some_label_name}` in a paragraph so that I can refer back to the particular point inside that paragraph where the `\LBL` was placed. I would like to define the macro for `\LBL.`

Unfortunately the `\label` must be placed inside an environment with a counter. I tried [phantomsection](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing#phantomsection) but the label picks up the true section counter. I'm using the hyperref package.

How can I achieve this, what would the `\def` for `\LBL` look like?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are many ways. The following is using `\refstepcounter` that generates implicitly an anchor. Also instead of a section number `\theword` is redefined to get the word instead, if called by `\ref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{word}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\LBL}{%
  \@dblarg\@LBL
}
\def\@LBL[#1]#2{%
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand*{\theword}{#2}%
    \refstepcounter{word}%
    \label{#1}%
    #2%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  The \ref{word} is referenced.

  \lipsum*[1] \LBL{word} \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

If the word is complicate that it cannot be used as label name, then the optional argument helps: `\LBL[labelword]{weird word}` … `\ref{labelword}`.

Comment: As it turned out, I would need more. Could you please check my [new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74944/8599)?