# How to refer back to a point in the document with custom counters?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, counters

The easiest way to explain what I would like to have is to show the desired output
[image: desired output]
and I would like to get this by writing something like:

```
\begin{document} 

Draw point B \STEP{drawb}. Connect A and B \STEP{connectab}. Draw point A \STEP{drawa}.

The correct order is \REF{drawa} then \REF{drawb} and finally 
\REF{connectab}.

\end{document}
```

The references should be links, so I can jump there by clicking it.

How should `\STEP` and `\REF` be defined?

The example is oversimplified. The referenced parts of the text cannot be put into an enumerate environment or whatnot, they are inside some paragraphs and must remain there. I am using latex and the hyperref package.

Feel free to edit the title, I have no idea how to phrase it in  consice way.

Comment: What are the dependencies of the numbering? The order of `\REF` commands?

Comment: Yes, exactly, in the order of the \REF commands.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Link from `\STEP` to `\REF`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{step}
\renewcommand*{\thestep}{Step~\arabic{step}}

\newcommand*{\REF}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \refstepcounter{step}%
    \label{#1}%
    \thestep
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand*{\STEP}[1]{%
  (\ref{#1})%
}

\begin{document}

Draw point B \STEP{drawb}. Connect A and B \STEP{connectab}. Draw point A
\STEP{drawa}.

The correct order is \REF{drawa} then \REF{drawb} and finally
\REF{connectab}.

\end{document}
```

> [image: Link from STEP to REF]

### Link from `\REF` to `\STEP`

Probably you want the links from `\REF` to `\STEP`. This solution puts anchors in both cases. Thus it can easily be extended to make links in both directions if needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[verbose]{hyperref}

\newcounter{step}
\renewcommand*{\thestep}{Step~\arabic{step}}

\newcommand*{\REF}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \refstepcounter{step}%
    \label{ref:#1}%
    \hyperref[{step:#1}]{\thestep}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand*{\STEP}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \phantomsection
    \label{step:#1}%
    (\ref*{ref:#1})%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Draw point B \STEP{drawb}. Connect A and B \STEP{connectab}. Draw point A
\STEP{drawa}.

The correct order is \REF{drawa} then \REF{drawb} and finally
\REF{connectab}.

\end{document}
```

> [image: Link from REF to STEP]

### Link from `\STEP` to `\REF` with `\ref`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[verbose]{hyperref}
\usepackage{refcount}[2010/12/01]

\makeatletter
\newcounter{step}
\renewcommand*{\thestep}{Step~\arabic{step}}

\newcommand*{\REF}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \refstepcounter{step}%
    \IfRefUndefinedBabel{step:#1}{%
    }{%
      \edef\@currentHref{%
        \getrefbykeydefault{step:#1}{anchor}{}%
      }%
    }%
    \label{#1}%
    \hyperref[{step:#1}]{\thestep}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand*{\STEP}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \phantomsection
    \label{step:#1}%
    (\ref*{#1})%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Draw point B \STEP{drawb}. Connect A and B \STEP{connectab}. Draw point A
\STEP{drawa}.

Additional reference: \ref{connectab}.

The correct order is \REF{drawa} then \REF{drawb} and finally
\REF{connectab}.

Additional references: \ref{drawa} and \ref{drawb}.

\end{document}
```

> [image: With additional \ref calls]

Comment: An unfortunate thing came up: if I reference for example drawa twice, then the everything becomes messed up. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: @Ali Example added for additional `\ref`s. It requires an additional LaTeX run, that makes three LaTeX runs.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS comes with an older refcount package and the document doesn't compile with that. Perhaps I could upgrade my LaTeX packages but the other co-authors, using institutional machines, can't. Is there a way to put this version of the refcount package under the $HOME directory and tell LaTeX to use it instead of the global one? Something like [here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/tex/tips-customstyles.html)?

Comment: See [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system).

Comment: I have a follow-up question. The discussion was getting too long here so I posted it as a new question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75950/8599). Could you look at it, please?

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** Example adjusted to new information.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{steps}

\newcommand*\refstep[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{steps}\label{#1}\hyperlink{step:#1}{step~\arabic{steps}}}
\newcommand*\step[1]{\hypertarget{step:#1}{step~\ref*{#1}}}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

Draw point B (\step{drawb}). Connect A and B (\step{connectab}).
Draw point A (\step{drawa}).

\newpage% to see that the links work

The correct order is \refstep{drawa} then \refstep{drawb} and finally 
\refstep{connectab}.

\end{document}
```

Original: How about something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{steps}
\newcommand*\step[1]{step~\ref{step:#1}}
\newcommand*\refstep[1]{step~\refstepcounter{steps}\thesteps\label{step:#1}}

\begin{document}

Draw point B (\step{drawb}). Connect A and B (\step{connectab}).
Draw point A (\step{drawa}).

The correct order is \refstep{drawa} then \refstep{drawb} and finally 
\refstep{connectab}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, the output is correct, thanks. But I also need it to be clickable (link) that is why I am using the hyperref package. Unfortunately your code doesn't compile with hyperref. :(

Comment: @Ali: add braces around `\ref{}`: `{\ref{step:#1}}`

Comment: Almost :) Now the referenced point is clickable, I would need the `\REF` to be the link.

Comment: @Ali: see edited answer

Comment: Something is still wird. It seems to jump to itself and not to the referenced location. :(

Comment: @Ali: the jump's just hidden… actually it works

Comment: Unfortunately it jumps to the line *below* the referenced location. I find it's very confusing that after clicking the link I cannot see the referenced place.

Comment: @Ali you can change the definition of `\step` to `\newcommand*\step[1]{\raisebox{1em}{\hypertarget{step:#1}{}}step~\ref*{#1}}` then you get the jump above the line instead of to the baseline.