# Add tag, label to several items in a list

Tags: lists, itemize

Is it possible to add a tag the way `aligned` environment does, but with `itemize`?

I want to achieve such a result

[image]

I managed to do that with this workaround, but it doesn't look neat for me.

```
\noindent My list
\begin{itemize}
    \item The first item\\[-6ex]
    \item[] \hfill(1)\label{items:1}\\[-6ex]
    \item The second item
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `parbox` to enclose the itemize list. I think it is also a good idea to define a new counter for be able to reference the tag (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74944/how-to-refer-back-to-a-point-in-the-document-with-custom-counters)).

```
\documentclass{article}
%
 
\newcounter{myitem}     
\renewcommand*{\themyitem}{(\arabic{myitem})}
\newcommand*{\mytag}[1]{%                            
  \begingroup                                        
    \refstepcounter{myitem}%                
    \label{#1}%                        
    \themyitem                         
  \endgroup                           
}                                     
                                      
                                      
\begin{document}                      
\noindent My list                     
                                      
\parbox[c]{0.9\linewidth}{            
  \begin{itemize}             
    \setlength\itemsep{0em}
    \item The first item                     
    \item The second item                    
  \end{itemize}                              
}                                            
\hfill\mytag{items:1}                        
                                      
                                                
See \ref{items:1}...                            
\end{document}
```

With `itemsep` you can set the spacing between items.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you use the `memoir` class (a superset of `book`, `report` and `article`) then it provides means of reducing the spaces between items.

```
% itemizeprob.tex  SE 543595

\documentclass{memoir}
%
\begin{document}
\noindent My list
\begin{itemize}
 %  \firmlist % reduce inter-item spaces
  \tightlist % eliminate inter-item spaces
  \item The first item \hfill(1)\label{items:1}
  \item The second item
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The class also provides declarations that reduce the inter-item spacing in all lists; see section *8.6 Lists* in the manual (`texdoc memoir`).