# How to reference a point in a document with a counter and descriptive text?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, counters

This is a follow-up question to the previous questions:

- [How to label a word inside a paragraph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74934/8599)
- [How to refer back to a point in the document with custom counters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74944/8599)

The code below

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{step}
\renewcommand*{\thestep}{(\textbf{Task~\arabic{step}})} % needed
\newcommand*{\TASK}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \refstepcounter{step}%
    \label{#1}%
    \thestep
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\REF}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \refstepcounter{step}%
    \phantomsection
     \ref{#1}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
text1 \TASK{t.limit} referenced as \REF{t.limit}.
\end{document}
```

gives me a text like this:

[image]

How should I modify it so that by writing

```
text1 \TASK{t.limit}{Limit behavior} referenced as \REF{t.limit}.
```

or something similar, I get the output below?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by modifying `\thestep` to also include the additional text:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{step}

\newcommand*{\Decription}{}%
\renewcommand*{\thestep}{(\textbf{Task~\arabic{step}}\Decription)} % needed
\newcommand*{\TASK}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \xdef\Decription{: #2}
    \refstepcounter{step}%
    \label{#1}%
    \thestep
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\REF}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \refstepcounter{step}%
    \phantomsection
     \ref{#1}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
text1 \TASK{t.limit}{Limit behavior} referenced as \REF{t.limit}
\end{document}
```