# using \ref for words in text - across files - and including urls

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, xr

So, I have a couple of questions, I'll try to build it up progressively:

1. I want to use labels and references for words or phrases instead of the usual reference to a section number or page. I found a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74934/how-to-label-a-word-inside-a-paragraph) - Heiko's solution - that works for me, so I can then use

   ```
   \LBL[A-01]{some phrase}
   ```

   and when I want to print out "some phrase" I use

   ```
   \ref{A-01}
   ```

   which works great. So far so good, but if anyone has any other ideas - especially in light of what follows, I would be happy to hear them.
2. Then I want to be able to use this system between files. So in one file I have a list of all the phrases (which might change at some point) and in another file I can just use `\ref` to get the phrases from the other file. I found simply adding  `\usepackage{xr}` and the appropriate `\externaldocument{}` command, that worked fine in conjunction with the `\LBL` code from above.
3. Now this is where it got too tricky for me. I want the 'some phrase' to actually be a url or rather href. So to get urls in the first place, I add the `hyperref` package, and then it seems the `xr` package gets all weird, which is fixed by using `xr-hyper` instead. 
   So I want the 'some phrase' to be the description of the href from the other file, AND I want clicking on it to take me to the url, and NOT to the other pdf.

Maybe this is too involved of an explanation, so I've got a minimal working example below - you have to name them file1.tex and file2.tex:

**file1.tex**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument{file2}

\newcounter{word}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\LBL}{%
  \@dblarg\@LBL
}
\def\@LBL[#1]#2{%
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand*{\theword}{#2}%
    \refstepcounter{word}%
    \label{#1}%
    #2%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ref{A-01}

\ref{A-02}
\end{document}
```

**file2.tex:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument{file1}

\newcounter{word}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\LBL}{%
  \@dblarg\@LBL
}
\def\@LBL[#1]#2{%
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand*{\theword}{#2}%
    \refstepcounter{word}%
    \label{#1}%
    #2%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\LBL[A-01]{some phrase}

\LBL[A-02]{\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{Best website ever}}

\end{document}
```

What happens now is that in file1.pdf both lines are hyperlinks to file2.pdf. But I want the first one to not be a clickable link at all, just normal text, and the second one to be the url hyperlink. I hope this makes sense.. How should I go about doing such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `hyperref` extends the syntax of `\ref` (and `\pageref`, ...) with a star form that creates a reference without hyperlink:

```
\ref*{A-01}
```

In the second case the reference data contains the complete `\href` expression, from `file2.aux`:

```
\newlabel{A-02}{{\href  {http://tex.stackexchange.com/}{Best website ever}}{1}{}{word.2}{}}
```

Thus `\ref{A-02}` generates a link to `file2.pdf` with destination `word.2` on top of the URL link. Also the star form helps to get rid of the top link:

```
\ref*{A-02}
```

Comment: Oh the beautiful simplicity. You are a life saver!